# Trigger recovery in Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am trying to configure a trigger in Zabbix in order to monitore a simple eventLog from a Windows server. The trigger works and an alarm raises but after 30s without this event it should get back to normal. But the problem is it never gets back to normal.

Here is the expression

```
{SERVER1:eventlog[Application,,,,15007,,skip].logeventid(15007)}=1
```

and

Recovery Expression

```
{SERVER1:eventlog[Application,,,,15007,,skip].nodata(30)}=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Here is the expression**

```
{SERVER1:eventlog[Application,,,,15007].logeventid(15007)}=1
and {SERVER1:eventlog[Application,,,,15007].nodata(30)}=0
```

**Recovery Expression**

```
{SERVER1:eventlog[Application,,,,15007].nodata(30)}=1
```